# Stripping everything except html tags using perl

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have been searching for a way to strip everything out of an html document leaving ONLY the html tags. Is anyone aware of a method for this? I have experience with many perl modules and have searched this site thoroughly.

I want to pass html as a string to my perl script and remove everything except the tags. Here is an example:

Incoming:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example Domain</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
div {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #38488f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    div {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
}
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    website content ....
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Becomes:

```
<html><head><title></title><meta><meta><meta><style></style></head><body><div><h1></h1>       <p></p><p><a></a></p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Becomes what? I hate it when people...

Comment: Fixed, first time dealing with the code tool on this site. ;)

Comment: You want to remove tag attributes as well?  If so, you should be able to do a reg ex like /</?\w+? ?>/

Comment: This should do the trick: `$text =~ s#[^<]*<(/?\w+).*?>[^<]*#$1#sg;`.

Comment: [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK8uY7) note that this will fail if the content contains `<` so you should really use DOM.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

Main( @ARGV );
exit( 0 );

sub Main {
    if( @_ ){
        nothing_but_tags("$_") for @_;
    } else {
        nothing_but_tags(q{<NoTe
KunG="FoO"
ChOp="SuEy"> 
NoteKungFo0Ch0pSuEy
<To KunG="FoO">ToKungFo0 
<Person KunG="FoO">Satan</Person>
</To>
<Beef KunG="FoO"> BeefKunGFoO <SaUsAGe KunG="FoO">is Tasty
</SaUsAGe>
</Beef>
</NoTe>},
        );
    }
}

sub nothing_but_tags
{
    my( $input, %opt ) = @_;

    $opt{pretty_print}  ||= 'indented' ;

    my $t = XML::Twig->new(
        %opt,
        force_end_tag_handlers_usage => 1,
        start_tag_handlers => {
            _all_ =>  sub {
                if( $_->has_atts ){
                    $_->set_atts ({});
                }
                return;
            },
        },
        end_tag_handlers => { _all_ =>  sub { $_->flush; return }, },
        char_handler => sub { '' },
    );
    $t->xparse( $_[0] );
    $t->flush();
    ();
}
__END__
<NoTe>
  <To>
    <Person></Person>
  </To>
  <Beef>
    <SaUsAGe></SaUsAGe>
  </Beef>
</NoTe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a transform is very simple with XSLT, so here's an example using XML::LibXSLT.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXSLT;

my $filename = $ARGV[0] or die("Usage: $0 filename\n");
my $doc      = XML::LibXML->load_html(location => $filename);

my $stylesheet_doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'EOF');
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF

my $xslt       = XML::LibXSLT->new;
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($stylesheet_doc);
my $result     = $stylesheet->transform($doc);

print $result->serialize_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understood well your question but to leave JUST THE TAGS you could take the output from strip tags (strip only tags) and then replace this output with null in the original text. In theory the first function will give you the exact text that is outside the tags and the next step will replace this text with null.